# How to check if the php script is running on a local server?

Tags: php, apache

Is it possible to check if the website (php) is running locally or on a hosted server?
I want to enable some logs if the website is running locally and I don't want these to appear on the site online..
I can set a variable `$local=1;` but I'll have to change that before uploading.. is there anyway to automate this task?

Local Server : WampServer 2.0 / Apache
WebServer: Apache

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=='127.0.0.1'`. This will only be true if running locally. Be aware that this means local to the server as well. So if you have any scripts running on the server which make requests to your PHP pages, they will satisfy this condition too.

Comment: Thanks that worked! `$local = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=='127.0.0.1' ? 1 : 0;` is what I used :)

Comment: Note that if you've done any kind of work on your network `127.0.0.1` may not be your server's IP address.  Be sure to replace the IP above with the actual IP of your server.

Comment: also allow for some servers (like Mac OSX) reporting the IPv6 value, so you would need: `$local = ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=='127.0.0.1' || '::1')` or similar. You can also use the HTTP_HOST value if your local environment uses a different host name like mysite.local, etc.

Comment: @Matthieu localhost doesn't matter since we're talking IP addresses. Thanks for the comments Charles and ldg!

Comment: @keppla's answer makes a lot more sense.

Comment: This works only on a web environment, won't work on PHP CLI.

Comment: @PabloPazos The question is explicitly asking about a web application.

Answer (score 8):

I believe the best approach is to 'fake' a testing mode, which can be done by creating a file in your local environment.
When I used this approach I created an empty text file called `testing.txt` and then used the following code:

```
if (file_exists('testing.txt')) {
    // then we are local or on a test environment
} else {
    // we are in production!
}
```

This approach is 100% compatible with any Operating System and you can use several test files in case you want a more granular approach (e.g. `development.txt`, `testing.txt`, `staging.txt`, or `production.txt`) in order to customise your deployment process.

Comment: It's hard to beat this solution, so I went with it. Thanks 

Answer (score 3):

**You should automate deployment**

This is not directly the answer to your question, but in my opinion the better way. In an automated deployment process, setting a variable like `$local = true`, like other configuration values (for example your db-connection), would be no manual, error prone, task.

Checking for 'localness' is in my opinion the wrong way: you dont want to show your logs to every local visitor (a Proxy may be one), but only *when deployed in a testing environment*.

A popular tool for automated deployment is [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki), there should be PHP-Centric tools too.

Comment: If someone is visiting your site via the web, the IP address you see will never be `127.0.0.1` (or `::1` for IPV6), regardless of the usage of a proxy. (Unless of course you're running the proxy yourself on the same server ;)

Comment: Jenkins and CruiseControl with PhpUnderControl are also good ones for continuous integration with PHP.

Comment: @Michael Mior: yes, that was the case, proxy on the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case this is useful to anybody, I made this function as the above answers didn't really do what I was looking for:

```
function is_local() {
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost'
        || substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,3) == '10.'
        || substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,7) == '192.168') return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: For the host IP address check, use `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`

Comment: Doesn't work on CLI.

Answer (score 1):

```
$whitelist = array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '::1'
);

if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $whitelist)){
    // not valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have build this function that checks if current **server name** has **name server** records, normally local server don't has.

```
<?php
function isLocal ()
{
  return !checkdnsrr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'NS');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your remote server is unlikely to have a C drive! So I run with this:

```
//Local detection
$root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
$parts = explode("/",$root);
$base = $parts[0];
$local = false;
if ($base == "C:") { 
 $local = true; //Change later for if local
}
```